# multiple bitmaps show up when rotating

Tags: java, android, bitmap, rotation

My project involves multiple concentric rings rotating around a central pivot point.  i initialize the surfaceview canvas with all the rings, then begin to rotate them from the innermost one to the outermost. The code works fine, but the problem is that the innermost ring, after 3 incremental rotations, begins to show up slightly out of sync with itself.  it's like multiple rings are showing up slightly out of phase with each other?

here's the code:

```
cSurface.setMatrix(mTmp);
cSurface.drawBitmap( wheels[idx], pivotX-(cD[idx]/2), pivotY-(cD[idx]/2), new Paint());
```

this code is used to both initialize the surfaceview and incrementally to rotate the rings.